# Excel 2010 - Break Links

Tags: excel

I have inherited an Excel 2010 file which, when I click on 'Edit Link', has two links to files I cannot access. These links cannot be updated and are no linger needed....but for the life of me I cannot delete, or break them!

I get the prompt:

> 'Breaking links permanently converts formulas and external references
>   to their existing values. Because this cannot be undone, you may wish
>   to save another copy of this file...Are you sure you want to break
>   links?'

To which I most vehemently reply by clicking 'Break links'.

Yet they are still there!!!!

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could break the links manually by finding the cells with external references and fixing their values.

To find cells with external links, do a find (ctrl-f) on all cells containing '{' (curly bracket).

Once you find a cell with an external link, highlight the cell and click F2 followed by F9 to fix the values (or Copy and Paste Values).

You could also try saving the file in the most current excel format - 'Edit Links' used to be very flakey and would never actually break the links, it has worked ok since 2013 though so perhaps the problem is in the old file format.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also check named ranges, charts, the linked cell on ActiveX controls.. probably a few other places to.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the sheet to new workbook

Right click on Sheet name>Move or Copy>new book

and copy paste the whole values as "Values and Number" formatting.

next save it as new workbook and delete your old version.